# Angular universal flickering

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I'm having a flicker while the website is loading.
The HTML coming form the server is downloaded and then in the UI the view is rendered and there is a small flicker between the transition.

I managed to fix it by adding:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([ // ROUTES HERE ], { initialNavigation: 'enabled' })
```

But I wanted to know why it happend? Because of the lazy loading of the components?
So we got a flicker between the transition while the UI (angular components) building the DOM? And let's say I had a 'light' component the flicker would be faster?

Answer (score 3):

Scroll down to the bold section for the answer,
read all of it for an explanation as to what is happening.

A very simplified explanation as to what is happening:

1.) A user goes to your application (or refreshes)

2.) The server builds the html in the server

3.) It gets sent to the browser where the user sees it

4.) The angular applications "re-creates" the application (as if it was a regular non-universal application)

5.) The user sees a flash when this change occurs.

```
// You can see this by adding:
// You should see a console log in the server
// `Running on the server with appId=my-app-id`
// and then you'll see in the browser console something like
// `Running on the browser with appId=my-app-id`
export class AppModule {
  constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object,
    @Inject(APP_ID) private appId: string) {
    const platform = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId) ?
      'in the browser' : 'on the server';
    console.log(`Running ${platform} with appId=${this.appId}`);
  }
}
```

This is intentional as you want bots to be able to pick up meta tags, etc.

**In order to remove the flash what you could do is transfer state from the server to the client:**

You will need to add this to your imports in your AppServerModule

`ServerTransferStateModule`

And you'll need to add this to your AppModule:

`BrowserTransferStateModule`

update the main.ts file to listen for DOMContentLoaded before bootstraping the browser app:

`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
})`

and then an example on how you transfer state:

```
import { tap, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { TransferState, makeStateKey } from '@angular/platform-browser';

const ANIMAL_KEY = makeStateKey<any>('animal');

// omitted ...

    ngOnInit() {
        const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('name').toLowerCase();
        this.animal$ = this.ssrFirestoreDoc(`animals/${id}`);
    }

    ssrFirestoreDoc(path: string) {
        const exists = this.state.get(ANIMAL_KEY, {} as any);
        return this.afs.doc<any>(path).valueChanges().pipe(
            tap(animal => {
                this.state.set(ANIMAL_KEY, animal)
                this.seo.generateTags({
                title: animal.name,
                description: animal.bio,
                image: animal.imgURL
            });
        }),
        startWith(exists))
    }
```

I got all of this from: 
[Angular Universal with Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wij2-gyG12E)
and
[Code and a more thorough explanation](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/server-side-rendering-firebase-angular-universal/)

Comment: and whay is `this.afs.doc<any>` supposed to be? I imagine the whole html for AppComponent. Do you mind explaining futherer?

Comment: this is the constructor:
`constructor(
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private seo: SeoService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private state: TransferState
  ) {}`

all it does it just listens to changes on the value that is return from firestore. this can easily be your own selector to some state. in this example we are just changing the title and meta tags based on the result we get from firestore.
Note i grabed all of this from https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/server-side-rendering-firebase-angular-universal/

Comment: BrowserTransferStateModule and ServerTransferStateModule are deprecated you can use TransferState directly

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well, but sadly for me the initialNavigatin didn't help. But, anyway, you can find details of "why" this happens at this github issue:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15716

> Confirmed. In my app all the routes are lazy loaded, using css with default ViewEncapsulation and angular starts removing the  tags with the ng-transition in browser, this process takes like a second. After the bootstrap finishes, it adds the styles back.
>   Here's how it looks like http://take.ms/1wizt

Hope this helps you understand, i'm still trying to fix this problem on my app

Comment: Did you found a solution? For me initialNavigation also doens't work ;/

Comment: yes. mine also flickers and does not have lazy loading or enabled also.

Answer (score 1):

@DonDaniel's answer is currect but slightly outdated.

In Angular 6+ you can use [TransferHttpCacheModule](https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/common).
[Official docs](https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/docs/transfer-http.md) explain how 3 lines changes do the magic.

And there is a [good article](https://www.twilio.com/blog/faster-javascript-web-apps-angular-universal-transferstate-api-watchdog) that compare the old way versus the new way.

Answer (score 1):

I also receive the same issue. SSR was loading twice.

```
Angular version : 14.0.4
Firebase version : 9.8.1
```

I had to replace the 'enabled' to `enabledBlocking` in `app-routing.module.ts` file.

```
const options: ExtraOptions = {
  preloadingStrategy: MyPreloadingStrategyService,
  scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled' ,
  initialNavigation : 'enabledBlocking',
  onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'
}
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, options)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

`MyPreLoadingStragegyService` page

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { PreloadingStrategy, Route } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyPreloadingStrategyService implements PreloadingStrategy {

  /** */
  constructor() { }

  /** 
   * It's used in lazy load module.
   * It's used to loaded Modules in the background asynchronously.
   * if route.data['preload'] true than preload else load on lazy load route.
   * @returns Observable
  */
  preload(route: Route, load: () => Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
    // console.log('route.data', route.data);
    if (route.data && route.data['preload']) {
      return load();
    } else {
      return of(null);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: what is MyPreloadingStrategyService in ExtraOptions? Could you please explain that?

Comment: @Rahul I have added the code for `MyPreloadingStrategyService` service file.

Comment: Can I directly add this MyPreLoadingStragegyService page to my project and make the app routing similar to yours to fix the solution?

Comment: Try first and if it doesnt work. let me know.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR;

In your **app.component.ts**:

- Add import

```
import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from "@angular/common";
```

- Add two variables:

```
this.isServer = isPlatformServer(this.platformId);
this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);
```

and hide server block from view with `display: none;` to prevent flickering

```
<div style="display: none" *ngIf="isServer">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<div *ngIf="isBrowser">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way to solve this problem.

display: none if the isPlatformServer().

Let's use CSS for it and enjoy life

and make yourself happy.

```
<div [ngStyle]=" isServer ? {'display':'none'}:{}">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div [ngStyle]=" isBrowser ? {}:{'display':'none'}">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).