# Angular universal load twice

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I try to add angular universal in my project. after adding it the page load twice in browser.
I am the owner of vichakshan.news so i try out this to solved the probleb

```
<section *ngIf="this.isBrowser" style="background-color: rgb(202, 202, 202);" >
    <div class="container" style="background-color: #fff;">
        <router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
    </div>
</section>
```

Now my page loading time is normal but can google read my data on web page ?

Comment: What is `this`? How do you define `isBrowser`?

Comment: this.isBrowser means isPlatformBrowser i had create a varible for that in ts file

Comment: constructor(private router: Router, private dialogRef: MatDialog, @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any) {
    this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
    this.isServer = isPlatformServer(platformId);
  }

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `this.isBrowser` means `isPlatformBrowser` function.

Google will crawl your webpage only on the server-side (where the prerender happens).

So the answer is no.

In order to check the data google will crawl you can use View Source or `curl` your website. What you see there is what google crawl.

By the way, the "load twice" happens because you first get the HTML of the prerendered page (by the server), and then a transition happens, after the JS in the client-side finishes loading.

There are some workarounds how to prevent the flickering effect, see [Angular universal flickering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49998277/angular-universal-flickering)